# Unity3d script applying rotation twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a simple space vehicle controller that allows for movement, yaw, roll, and pitch.  it works great on each axis individually, but when I both yaw and roll, pitch and move, etc. the rotations are incorrct.  I believe something is happening twice, because when the vehicle is at a 90 degree angle of pitch it moves horizontally when it should move vertically (90 degrees off at 90 degrees rotation).  AT 45 it is somwhere in the middle.  At 0 it works as expected.

My full code is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Input : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float moveAcceleration = 50f;
    public float maxMoveSpeed = 500f;
    public float turnAcceleration = 30f;
    public float maxTurnSpeed = 100f;
    public float rotAcceleration = 30f;
    public float maxRotSpeed = 100f;

    private float moveSpeed = 0;
    private float pitchSpeed = 0;
    private float yawSpeed = 0;
    private float rollSpeed = 0;
    private Vector3 angle = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("w")) {
            moveSpeed += moveAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(Input.GetKey("s")) {
            moveSpeed -= moveAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(moveSpeed > 10f) {
            moveSpeed -= 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }else if(moveSpeed < -10f) {
            moveSpeed += 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(!Input.GetKey("w") && !Input.GetKey("s")) {
            moveSpeed = 0f;
        }

        moveSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(moveSpeed, -maxMoveSpeed, maxMoveSpeed);


        if(Input.GetKey("a")) {
            yawSpeed += turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(Input.GetKey("d")) {
            yawSpeed -= turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        }       

        if(yawSpeed > 10f) {
            yawSpeed -= 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }else if(yawSpeed < -10f) {
            yawSpeed += 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(!Input.GetKey("a") && !Input.GetKey("d")) {
            yawSpeed = 0f;
        }

        yawSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(yawSpeed, -maxTurnSpeed, maxTurnSpeed);

        if(Input.GetKey("left")) {
            rollSpeed += rotAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(Input.GetKey("right")) {
            rollSpeed -= rotAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        }        

        if(rollSpeed > 10f) {
            rollSpeed -= 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }else if(rollSpeed < -10f) {
            rollSpeed += 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(!Input.GetKey("left") && !Input.GetKey("right")) {
            rollSpeed = 0f;
        }

        rollSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(rollSpeed, -maxRotSpeed, maxRotSpeed);

        if(Input.GetKey("up")) {
            pitchSpeed += turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(Input.GetKey("down")) {
            pitchSpeed -= turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        }        

        if(pitchSpeed > 10f) {
            pitchSpeed -= 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }else if(pitchSpeed < -10f) {
            pitchSpeed += 5f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(!Input.GetKey("up") && !Input.GetKey("down")) {
            pitchSpeed = 0f;
        }

        pitchSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(pitchSpeed, -maxTurnSpeed, maxTurnSpeed);


        this.transform.Translate(moveSpeed * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
        angle += Time.deltaTime * ((pitchSpeed * transform.right) + (rollSpeed * transform.forward) + (yawSpeed * transform.up));
        //Debug.Log(transform.forward);
        this.transform.eulerAngles = angle;

    }
}
```

The relevant bit is at the end (acceleration and such work as intended), just where the angles are set.  The transforms are correct (I have checked), but the movements applied are not.  Do you see the issue?

Thanks, I apreciate it!

Edit:  there is also only 1 instance of the script on the GameObject, just to narrow it down a little more.

Edit 2: I found [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-transform-forward-returns-wrong-values-when-rotating.469236/) forum post that seems to have the same issue, but I don't think I have done the same thing that this person has.  Maybe a good starting place?

Edit 3: I feel like the "angle += ..." line is the culprit, but I can't tell why.  Maybe look there.

Comment: As a rule you should never set a rotation with `.eulerAngles`, use the `Quaternion` class instead which handles the kind of problems you're having: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/quaternions

Comment: @Absinthe I didn't realize the gimbal lock issue (I vaguely knew about it, but didn't think about it).  However, as the video said, I should not alter quaternion properties individually.  How should I go about adding these individual rotations to the object?  Thanks!

Comment: I found some things like `Quaternion.AngleAxis`, is that the sort of thing I am looking for?

Comment: `AngleAxis` only rotates on one axis. In your case you could try `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle)`. If that doesn't work play around with the other methods in that class like like `LookRotation` which takes a direction vector. I'm at work so can't test for you, the ref is here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

Comment: @Absinthe Sorry for the late reply, I was getting my wisdom teeth removed.  I have tried some of these things and have not had any sucess, but I have had some insights.  I have checked, and `transform.[axis]` all are correct.  The object is always pointing the correct direction that `angle` specifies, and that direction changes incorrectly.  I feel that the issue lies with some faulty logic on line 98, but I can't spot it.  Could the values be in radians or something?  Just to emphasize, every axis works individually, but add any rotation and nothing works.  Would you like a screen...

Comment: ...recording so you can see the issue?  I really appreciate the help, I have been doing this for a few years but still struggle with these concepts sometimes.  Cheers, and have a good night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Quaterion` class to avoid gimbal lock and multiply the current rotation with the new additional rotation. I've modified the last few lines of your script:

```
> angle = new Vector3(pitchSpeed, yawSpeed, rollSpeed);
> transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(angle);
> transform.Translate(moveSpeed * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

You'll want to greatly reduce these, I divided them by 10 which seemed pretty smooth:

```
public float turnAcceleration = 30f;
public float maxTurnSpeed = 100f;
public float rotAcceleration = 30f;
public float maxRotSpeed = 100f;
```

Not sure if you wanted the yaw to be in the direction pressed or inverted, currently if you press left it yaws right, you can invert these if required:

```
if(Input.GetKey("a")) {
   yawSpeed += turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
} else if(Input.GetKey("d")) {
   yawSpeed -= turnAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

If you're making a space game you might want to consider smoothing out `moveSpeed , pitchSpeed, yawSpeed, rollSpeed` with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html to make the motions more realistic.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the time you have put into helping me out!  I will mark this as the correct answer once I test in in an hour or so.  Have a nice day!

Comment: No probs, send me a link to where I can buy the game when it's done :). Updated the answer with a link to  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html in case you want all 3 axis damped at the same rate, use it to damp `angle` instead of the individual floats with the `Mathf` version.